# TimeoutException does not OPEN circuit in resilience4j. Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am using below code, and what I have seen is `BulkheadFullException` and `RuntimeException` is changing the state of circuitbreaker from `CLOSED` to `OPEN`, whereas that's not the case with `TimeoutException`.

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "primary", fallbackMethod = "fallbackHandler")
@TimeLimiter(name = "primary")
@Bulkhead(name = "primary", type = Type.THREADPOOL)
public CompletableFuture<String> primaryHandler(String input) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(process(input));
}

public Object process(String input) {
    
    // TimeoutException will be thrown here by TimeLimiter as timeout is set to 10 seconds.
    try {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    
    return null;
}

public CompletableFuture<Object> fallbackHandler(String input, Exception e) {

    // 1. timeout exception is being captured here, but it's not opening the circuit breaker.
    // 2. BulkheadfullException is also being captured here, which is opening the circuit breaker.
    // 3. Any other RuntimeException which is captured here is opening the circuit breaker.

    log.error("primary fallback triggered. Error:", e);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

Q1. Why would `TimeoutException` not consider as a failure in the resilience4j ? Does `Hystrix` follows the same behaviour.

**My requirement** :

1. I need CircuitBreaker to consider `TimeoutException`s as a failures with other already present exceptions.
2. I need to to rethrow all exceptions(except `BulkheadfullException` and `CallNotPermittedException`) to the caller.

**Reason** -> MDC does not gets propagated to the `fallbackMethod` in case of `TimeoutException` and other `RuntimeException`s as they gets executed in a different thread pool than the parent threadpool in resilience4j. Because of this context information gets lost and logs in fallback method in case of `TimeoutException` does print the MDC variables. Checked the github issue for this, seems this is not yet solved.

I want to rethrow then in `fallbackMethod`, thus caller can catch and log them with the context information, hence no context info will be lost. Whereas in case of `BulkheadfullException` and `CallNotPermittedException`, fallback gets executed in the parent thread itself thus context information never gets lost here for these exceptions.

Is this possible in resilience4j?

Comment: Have you tried to specify `TimeoutException` via the `recordExceptions` ([ref](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#create-and-configure-a-circuitbreaker))?

Comment: @ref yes, Tried that as well `TimeoutException` in `recordExceptions` still not working.